# Turn multidimensional array column into single array

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have a multidimensional array

```
Array ( 
[0] => Array ( [0] => 4 [1] => 2200 ) 
[1] => Array ( [0] => 7 [1] => 2050 ) 
[2] => Array ( [0] => 2 [1] => 1000 ) 
[3] => Array ( [0] => 3 [1] => 900 ) 
[4] => Array ( [0] => 8 [1] => 430 ) 
[5] => Array ( [0] => 5 [1] => 400 ) 
[6] => Array ( [0] => 1 [1] => 200 ) 
[7] => Array ( [0] => 6 [1] => 20 ) 
)
```

I would like to take all the column 0 and turn it into its own array. How can I do this without using loops?

I have used loops but I want a cleaner way.

Comment: This isn't a coding service, what have you tried?

Comment: Its a question service, this is a question

Comment: And you're asking for someone to write code for you. So if you want an answer, you need [`foreach()`](http://php.net/foreach) or [`array_column()`](http://php.net/array_column).  Good luck champ.

Comment: @user3565264 you are still expected to try something.

Comment: It's not a service at all.

Comment: DUDEs, all I needed was "array_column" chill

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[array_column](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-column.php) do the job. (php >= 5.5)

For php < 5.5 see [this comment](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-column.php#113375).

Comment: This is was I was looking for! Perfect